# CSS - Alterar distância do texto e a imagem de um list item

Tags: html, css

Tenho a seguinte lista ordenada:

```css
        ol{
            list-style: none;
         counter-reset: item;
         list-style-position: outside;
        }
        ol li  {
         counter-increment: item; 
         margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        ol li::before{
         margin-right: 10px;
         content: counter(item);
         border-radius: 100%;
         color: #2388ED;
         border: 2px solid #2388ED;
         text-align: center;  
         display: inline-block;
         padding: 4px 10px;
         font-family: sans-serif;
         font-weight: bolder;
         font-size: 1.5em;
        }
```

```html
<body>
        <ol>
            <li>
                “Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning.” 
                ― Rick Cook, The Wizardry Compiled
            </li>
            <li>
                “Talk is cheap. Show me the code.” 
                ― Linus Torvalds
            </li>
        </ol>
    
    </body>
```

A minha duvida era saber como eu altero a distância entre a imagem da minha list item 'modificada' e o texto, para deixar o texto alinhado com a primeira linha após as quebras de linha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um pseudo elemento `::before` ou `::after` é sempre um filho direto do próprio elemento que o recebe.

*Imagem retirada direto do Chrome DevTools*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo:

```
<li>
    ::before
    texto
    ::after
</li>
```

Então eu usei `display:flex` na `LI` e ajuste os itens para ficar em linha e de forma centralizada.

Veja o exemplo como fica:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ol li  {
    counter-increment: item;    
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
ol li::before{
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: counter(item);
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #2388ED;
    border: 2px solid #2388ED;
    text-align: center;     
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        “Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning.” 
        ― Rick Cook, The Wizardry Compiled
    </li>
    <li>
        “Talk is cheap. Show me the code.” 
        ― Linus Torvalds
    </li>
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laboriosam ipsam vero tenetur. Exercitationem, voluptate cupiditate. Ducimus nesciunt quos sit ratione perspiciatis natus atque dolores ab, minima facere quae saepe nostrum asperiores, velit voluptas molestias dolor ex labore cum expedita vero inventore. Nobis rem natus culpa voluptas maxime enim quisquam in, sequi eum consequatur veniam optio cumque, ullam dolore quas vero debitis quis mollitia facilis. A animi nihil fugiat aliquid qui veniam repellendus, optio tempore ratione obcaecati quisquam illum, aspernatur libero. Fugit magnam, minima neque dignissimos laboriosam adipisci enim asperiores labore quaerat nesciunt ipsum explicabo ratione quae dolore soluta distinctio blanditiis?
    </li>
</ol>
```